# Verbose Log Message appeared from inside Android

Tags: android

I have just switch back to the Android build after a while away to fix some final issues.  However when I run my build I get this message spammed constantly:

```
AudioHardwareMSM7X30( 1267): AudioStreamOutMSM72xx::getParameter route=8
```

This looks very similar (other than the 1267 which is a line number?) to a message in AudioHardware.cpp that I found at..

[vogue-android.googlecode.com/hg/eclair2.0](http://vogue-android.googlecode.com/hg/eclair2.0)

I am running on a Evo Shift with the stock OS, not rooted or anything.  Could someone tell me where this message is coming from and how to shut it off?